# Wordpress Website not showing favicon in SERP

Tags: wordpress, themes, favicon

We have a website: https://aurummetalinvest.ie/

It only recently came to our attention that the SERP favicon is showing the default Wordpress icon.

The icon has been set in the Site Identity option [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcpJR.png) and it has been that way for years.

The favicon set shows correctly on the tab, bookmark, etc. but not in the [Google Search results page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZCM2.png).

Checking with Google for the favicon it has received, it still [shows the Wordpress default icon](https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=aurummetalinvest.ie).

I have read there used to be a manual way to put it in via a small HTML code on homepage but apparently it is no longer necessary.

Please can someone assist? The theme we are using is called Kapee from ThemeForest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I have read there used to be a manual way to put it in via a small HTML code on homepage but apparently it is no longer necessary.

There is a way, and Google's documentation indicates it's necessary.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/favicon-in-search

> Here's how to make your site eligible for a favicon in Google Search results:
>
> 1. Create a favicon that follows the [guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/favicon-in-search#guidelines).
> 2. Add a `<link>` tag to the header of your home page with the following syntax: `<link rel="icon" href="/path/to/favicon.ico">`

Comment: Thanks. I have read this but then read people on Wordpress saying not needed, but anyway, I'll try it. Am I doing it correcty here? https://prnt.sc/l6o9bZ9Zrp59

Comment: @YamiPrem No, it needs to go in your site's `<head>`, and on every page, not just one.

Comment: Ah, will need  to find the header. Also, Google only mentions the homepage.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/hzJd6cQoRz-_
This should do it, I hope!